# Revisited: How to launch a KDE konsole with multiple tabs running various progs?

Tags: kde-plasma, debian-buster, konsole

As the title strongly suggests, I have already read [How to launch a KDE konsole with multiple tabs running various progs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779281/how-to-launch-a-kde-konsole-with-multiple-tabs-running-various-progs), and the answer is just what I need - except, I want to set the remote title, and I don't find any options for that. I can see elsewhere that it should be possible to do from the command line, but I'd rather use this config-file method, if possible. Is there an option for that?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me cmd;
konsole  --tabs-from-file `/settings/s-tab-file

`cat /settings/s-tab-file`

```
title: Pay6 1 ;; command: ~/bin/pay_index    # scripts that call functions 
title: Sal6 2 ;; command: ~/bin/sales_index #  <---[ scripts fails unless contains    #! /bin/sh  ]---
title: Led6 3 ;; command: ~/bin/ledger_index
```

above is 3 separate lines, i  had to put a space line because post
turned them into one long line.

worked great right up to kubuntu 18.04  3 konsole tabs as expected
problem I'm having now is Kubuntu 20.04 is giving me a 4th trailing empty konsole
that looks stupid and has to be removed to look proper.

Comment: without line feeds that looks confusing to me, and I know what it means, how do you post multiple lines,